# Using the same controller instances as yielded by the "control" helper

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js, ember-data

With the following models :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  comments: DS.hasMany 'App.Comment'

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend
  body: DS.attr 'string'
  post: DS.belongsTo 'App.Post'
```

I'm displaying all posts and all post comments in my posts template :

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{post.title}}
  {{#each comment in post.comments itemController="comment"}}
    {{partial 'comment' comment}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The control helper is used here so that I get a controller for each comment.

I have a CommentsController who's model is a flattened array of comments taken from the posts.

```
App.CommentsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'comment'
  needs: 'posts'
  postsBinding: 'controllers.posts'

  comments: (->
    comments = []
    @get('posts').forEach (post) ->
      post.get('comments').forEach (comment) ->
        comments.pushObject comment
    console.log comments
    @set 'model', comments
  ).observes('posts.length')

App.CommentController = Em.ObjectController.extend()
```

This controller does decorate each record with the CommentController as expected, however it seems to be creating new controller instances instead of reusing the controllers that are being rendered in the template. Is there a way of finding the same instances?

Answer (score 0):

By design, each `{{control}}` helper will create new instances of your controller. Sounds like what you are looking for is provided out-of-box by the `{{each}}` helper.

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{post.title}}
  {{each comment in post.comments itemViewClass="App.ItemView" itemController="item"}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I'm actually still getting duplicated controllers - could it be that my `comments` method is creating these duplicates instead of find existing instances?

Comment: I don't see anything in the `comments` method that would do that. Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. You said "it seems to be creating new controller instances instead of reusing the controllers that are being rendered in the template". When exactly is it creating new controller instances. How do you even know?

Comment: OK, I've just added code regarding how I'm loggin each instance - basically just printing out the objects in the template or via `console.log`. I am getting CommentController instances, but they're not the same in the template as in the CommentsController.

The instances created from CommentsController are bound to the `posts` array which is a collection fetched with ember-data.